# How to use % or ! in batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I write script like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "remove=ABC"
echo. %remove%
Set FILENAME="456_789_ABC00011092_789_EFGHIK_56893.mpg"

for %%a in (%FILENAME:_=" "%) do (
    set TEN=%%a
    echo. %AB%
    set "remove_1=ABC"
    echo. %remove_1%
    Set _TEN=!TEN:%remove%=!
    echo. %_TEN%
    Set i=0
    IF !_TEN! NEQ !TEN! (
      set /A i+=1
      set "String[!i!]=%%~a"
    )
)
pause
exit
```

Why `echo. %AB%` `echo. %remove_1%` result is

I replace `%` by `!`. It's work fine but command `Set _TEN=!TEN:!remove_1!=!` not run

---

**Edit** - *(from the additional question currently posted as an answer)*

When I use FindStr command like this:

```
for %%a in (%FILENAME:_=" "%) do (
    echo %%a | findstr /I /R /C:"ABC" >nul
    ECHO %errorlevel%
    if "%errorlevel%" equ "0" (
        set /A i+=1
        set "String[!i!]=%%~a"
        )
    )
```

Why `errorlevel`  always = `0`

Comment: `%AB%` has not been defined within your posted script, so as it has no value will not be `echo`ed, you will just get an empty line due to the **`.`** after `echo`. Because `remove_1` is being set within the loop, _(code block)_, you should be using the delayed expansion syntax, `Echo !remove_1!`. It is the same for `echo. %_TEN%`, i.e. `Echo !_TEN!`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%AB%` has not been defined within your posted script, so as it has no value will not be `echo`ed, you will just get an empty line due to the **`.`** after `echo`. Because `remove_1` is being set within the loop, *(code block)*, you should be using the delayed expansion syntax, `Echo !remove_1!`. It is the same for `echo. %_TEN%`, i.e. `Echo !_TEN!`, and would have been `Echo !AB!` had it previously been defined. In order to get the double expansion needed to `Set` your `_TEN` variable, you could use a pseudo `Call`:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "FILENAME=456_789_ABC00011092_789_EFGHIK_56893.mpg"

For %%A In ("%FILENAME:_=" "%") Do (
    Set "TEN=%%A"
    Echo. !AB!
    Set "remove_1=ABC"
    Echo !remove_1!
    Call Set "_TEN=!TEN:%%remove_1%%=!"
    Echo !_TEN!
    Set "i=0"
    If "!_TEN!" NEq "!TEN!" (
        Set /A i+=1
        Set "String[!i!]=%%~A"
    )
)
Pause
Exit /B
```

In your second related question, *initially posted as an answer and now added as an edit to your original question*; because the error level is being `set` within the loop, *(code block)*, you should be using the delayed expansion syntax, `!errorlevel!`

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "FILENAME=456_789_ABC00011092_789_EFGHIK_56893.mpg"

For %%A In ("%FILENAME:_=" "%") Do (
    Echo %%A | FindStr /IRC:"ABC" >Nul
    Echo !errorlevel!
    If "!errorlevel!"=="0" (
        Set /A i+=1
        Set "String[!i!]=%%~A"
    )
)
Set String[
Pause
Exit /B
```

Or if you don't need to `Echo` each error level to the screen, you can use a conditional statement `&&`:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "FILENAME=456_789_ABC00011092_789_EFGHIK_56893.mpg"

For %%A In ("%FILENAME:_=" "%") Do (
    Echo %%A | FindStr /IRC:"ABC" >Nul && (
        Set /A i+=1
        Set "String[!i!]=%%~A"
    )
)
Set String[
Pause
Exit /B
```

Comment: Thanks. Now, I understand how to use variable in loop.

Comment: Which script should I use?